# PSM: reproducing results from kmatch with psmatch2 in Stata

Tags: kernel, stata, matching, propensity-score-matching

I am working on Propenstiy Score Matching with Stata 17.

I use userwritten command `kmatch` to automatically estimate the bandwith for kernel matching, but I prefer the balancing outputs of `psmatch2`.

Hence, I estimate the optimal bandwith with `kmatch`, copy paste it into `psmatch2` and run the command. However, they don't match the same number of observations although (as far as I see) the specifications are the same. I guess one command has some default setting that I don't see that makes the results different.

For example the following commands produce a similar ATT but the former only uses half as many control observations.

```
kmatch ps D (Y), pscore(PSD) kernel(epan) bwidth(0.05) att

psmatch2 D, outcome(Y) pscore(PSD) kernel bwidth(0.05)
```

`kmatch` ends up using less control observations than  `psmatch2`.
Epan. is the default kernel for `psmatch2` hence it is not specified. ATT is also the default. D and Y do not have any missings.

I want to understand where the difference comes from.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1499320-kmatch-bandwidth

Comment: I think that psmatch2 when ATT is specified just puts all controls on support. There is no need to exclude any controls so they are all "on support" but this does not mean that they are in fact matched! (_weight stores a value for each unit that is used, so here one can see which control unit was matched).  This could explain why the number of units "used" differs, but not why the results are different.